# Tic-Tac-Toe Strategy - 60's MiniVac 601 Logic

Tags: algorithm, history

Tic-Tac-Toe seems to be a fairly solved problem space, most 100% solutions seem to search through a finite tree of possibilities to find a path to winning.

However, I came across something from a computer-simulation toy from the 60's, The MiniVac 601. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minivac_601

This 'comptuer' consisted of 6 relays that could be hooked up to solve various solutions. It had a game section, which had this description on a program for Tic-Tac-Toe, that claims to be unbeatable as long as the Minivac went first.

Since most solutions to this seem to require lots of memory or computational power, its surprising to see a solution using a computer of 6 relays. Obviously I haven't seen this algorithm before, not sure I can figure it out. Attempts to solve this on a pad and paper seem to indicate a fairly easy win against the computer.

http://www.ccapitalia.net/descarga/docs/1961-minivac601-book5&6.pdf

> "with this program, MINI VAC can not lose. The human opponent may
>   tie the game, but  he can never win. This is because of the decision
>   rules which are the basis of the program. **The M IN IV A C is so
>   programmed that the machine will move 5 squares to the right of its 
>   own last move if and only if the human opponent has blocked that last
>   move by moving 4 squares  to the right of the machine's last move. If
>   the human player did not move 4 squares to the right  of the machine's
>   last move, M IN IV A C will move into that square and indicate a win.
>   If the hu­ man player consistently follows the "move 4 to the right"
>   rule, every game will end in a tie.** This program requires that M IN IV
>   A C make the first move; the machine's first move will  always be to
>   the center of the game matrix. A program which would allow the human
>   opponent  to move first would require more storage and processing
>   capacity than is available on M IN IV A C 
>   601. Such a program would, of course, be much more complex than the program which permits  the machine to move first"

EDIT: OK so the Question a little more explicitly: Is this a real solution to solving Tic-Tac-Toe? Does anyone recognize this algorithm, it seems very very simple to not be easily searchable.

Comment: Circa 1970 I saw a machine like this demonstrated at Bell Labs on a tour.  I was very young, but it made an impression on me.

Comment: I am not certain, but from the description I get the impression that this is a much simplified version of tic-tac-toe that they are talking about, namely the variant played on a one-dimensional board.

Comment: The question is, can anyone help figure out the algorithm described and if it really is a unbeatable strategy if the computer goes first.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is all in the layout of the "board". If you look at the 601 units tic-tac-toe area, 9 is in the middle and 1 is top left numbered sequentially clockwise around 9.
The "computer" goes first in the 9 position. The user then goes next. 
If the user hasn't gone in position 1 (top left) then that is the next position for the computer. The user then goes next. Then the computer tries to go in position 1+4 (5 - bottom right). If the position is not available it will go in 1+5 (6 - bottom middle). x + 4 is always opposite the previous move, and since the computer has the center position it will be a winning move.